# variable in expl3 case function does not seem to expand/substitue (code compiles but strange output)

Tags: macros, tex-core, conditionals, expl3

the provided code copy-paste ready and compiles.

**Problem**:
the `\l_secondIndex_tl` variable does not seem to expand to its stored value in the `\tl_case:NnF` -line and therefore the code does not find the case correctly. (It outputs "No case found" instead of "one" in the first test case).

In case I hardcode the value `\l_secondIndex_tl` to `1` , the code outputs "one" for all test cases, as expected (since the value is hard coded, the input does not matter).

**Question**:
How can i make the code work as intended? (How to enforce the variable to expand itself to its value?)

**Idea**: The command receives 2 digits (no separator between them) and checks the second one and outputs the message of the corresponding case.

Thank you very much for any help in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3} % To me, it was not necessary to load in.

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m}{
    %
    \tl_set:Nn   \l_firstIndex_tl   { \tl_use:N {#1} {1} }
    \tl_set:Nn   \l_secondIndex_tl { \tl_use:N {#1} {2} }
    %
    \tl_case:NnF \l_secondIndex_tl
    {
        {1} { one   }
        {2} { two   }
        {3} { three }
    }
    {No~case~found.}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Test the code:
\par \mycommand{21} \% Not OK - expected output: "one"
\par \mycommand{26} \% OK - expected output: "No case found."
\par \mycommand{2a} \% OK - expected output: "No case found."
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `\tl_use:N #1 {1}` supposed to do ? `#1` is the argument, so you are writing there `\tl_use:N 21 {1}` which looks quite nonsensical.

Comment: it would help if you said what this code was intended to do, we can explain its current output but it is hard to guess what it is intended to do. why do you expect the first `21`  case to return `one` ??

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, you are right. I meant  ``` \tl_set:Nn \l_si_tl { \tl_item:Nn {#1} {2} } ```
(I correct this in the code now: [old:] ```\tl_set:Nn   \l_secondIndex_tl { \tl_use:N #1 {2} }```  [to]: ``` \tl_set:Nn   \l_secondIndex_tl { \tl_use:N {#1} {2} } ```.  I do the same change in the line above, namely ```#1``` --> ```{#1}``` ) . (I only write all of these, if once one tries to follow the thread.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I add a short description now.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer for you as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the use of `\tl:use:N` appears wrong but from the desired output I guess you want

[image]

which is obtained from

```
\documentclass{article}
% only needed for old latex \usepackage{expl3} 

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m}{
    %
    \tl_set:Nx   \l_firstIndex_tl   { \use_i:nn #1 }
    \tl_set:Nx   \l_secondIndex_tl { \use_ii:nn #1 }
    %
    \str_case:VnF \l_secondIndex_tl
    {
        {1} { one   }
        {2} { two   }
        {3} { three }
    }
    {No~case~found.}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Test the code:
\par \mycommand{21} \% Not OK - expected output: "one"
\par \mycommand{26} \% OK - expected output: "No case found."
\par \mycommand{2a} \% OK - expected output: "No case found."
\end{document}
```

(answer updated to use `\str_case:VnF` in place of `exp_args:NV\tl_case:NnF` whch is cleaner and avoids using an N rgument with a character token (which works but is a mild abuse as it's supposed to be a command name token))

Comment: Thank you David, it does the job! ^^


May I ask you some questions for better understanding some functions?

What is the difference between ``` \tl_set:Nn   \l_si_tl { \tl_item:Nn  {#1} {2} }``` and ```\tl_set:Nx   \l_sii_tl { \use_ii:nn #1 }``` ? 
 
both of them leaves the same digit in the output steam, if I write them in the code after them being declared. For example if ```#1 = {21}```, both will leave ```1```  in the output stream. Since, they do so, I assumed, that those variables gets expanded at compilation. (...continues in the next comment...)

Comment: (...continuation...)
 But:  I am wondering why the variable did not expand, when I used after ```\tl_case:NnF``` ?

 Regarding the ```\tl_use``` function: one of my earlier attempt was involving this. If i would declare ```\tl_set:Nn \l_myTwo_tl {2}```  (which would return in the output stream ```2``` if I was just calling after declaration), and then i would substitute the ```{2} { two   }``` line with ```{\tl_use:N \l_one_tl} { two   }```, the code would output ```two``` instead of ```one```
(...continuing in the next comment...)

Comment: @keenOnTex your question used `\tl_use:N` (which does nothing useful at all here) not `tl_item`   `\tl_item:nn` is more general but slower than `\use_i:nn` which is `\@firstoftwo` so selects the first of two items in a single expansion step

Comment: `\tl_case` doesn't expand its test argument, which is why I prefixed with `\exp_args:NV` to expand it (once) @keenOnTex

Comment: . This I found interesting. Does ```\tl_use``` literally force the case structure to use the value, on which \tl_use is applied? (and if there is more ```\tl_use```, then the first occurence?)

Why does without ```\exp_args:NV ``` the ```\tl_case:NnF``` not working as expected? Does this mean, that one always needs to use ```\exp_args:NVF``` with ```\tl_case:NnF``` ?

(... end of continuations.)

Comment: @keenOnTex not sure what you find surprising, if you have `\def\z{x} \def\a{x} \def\b{\z}`  then `\a` and `\b` both expand eventually to `x` but they are not `\ifx` equal unless you expand `b` once. That's all that is happening here, the tests in `tl_case` all fail unless you expand the first argument once, which is what `\exp_args:NV` does.

Comment: thank you for all the useful notes!  I started with expl3 three days ago, that is why I can be easily surprised :) You mentioned the speed of commands: how could one find out, which command is faster/slower?

Comment: I'm afraid this works by pure accident. See my answer. I'm sure you can understand why your code *seems* to work (hint: `\ifx`).

Comment: @keenOnTex Please, look at my answer. This one is wrong.

Comment: @egreg well it relies on the test value being known to be a single token which is true after the x expansion for the definition and the V to extract the value. So not accidental, just only applicable to this restricted use case.

Comment: @keenOnTex I started with this l3 syntax in 1992, so I have had longer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, it remains wrong.

Comment: @egreg as I say it wasn't wrong just pushing the limits of N argument use, but anyway I switched it to `\str_case` now so you should be happy:-)

Comment: I tried to execute \mycommand{α1}, but The greek alpha seems to be swallowed [alphanumeric characters instead of alpha work as expected]. Without compiling with xelatex or \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}, the compilation fails. With which package (without xelatex) was it possible to use this macro correctly and keep this form of input method?

Comment: @keenOnTex if you need to specify utf8 inputenc you  have a very old latex, it has been the default for several years

Comment: pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.3
...
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03

it does not seem to be old, i just try to find ways of displaying the greek character, without issuing their command (like \alpha) ^^

Comment: the version of pdftex does not matter but you are unlikely to be using a an old latex with texlive 2021, so `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` does nothing at all as utf8 is the default. @keenOnTex

Comment: I just wrote, that the problem is not solved with either of the possibilities i sketched, to avoid receiving any of those as reply. I use neither of them. (didnt know what info was needed so i just copied what i thought it might be)

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding how `\tl_case:Nn(TF)` works. It compares token string variables with token string variables, not with explicit token lists like `\str_case:nn(TF)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3} % To me, it was not necessary to load in.

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m}
  {
    \keenontex_index:n { #1 }
  }

\tl_new:N \l_keenontex_index_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l_keenontex_index_second_tl

\tl_const:Nn \c_keenontex_index_one_tl { 1 }
\tl_const:Nn \c_keenontex_index_two_tl { 2 }
\tl_const:Nn \c_keenontex_index_three_tl { 3 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \keenontex_index:n
  {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_keenontex_index_first_tl  { \tl_item:nn {#1} {1} }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_keenontex_index_second_tl { \tl_item:nn {#1} {2} }
    %
    \tl_case:NnF \l_keenontex_index_second_tl
      {
        \c_keenontex_index_one_tl   { one   }
        \c_keenontex_index_two_tl   { two   }
        \c_keenontex_index_three_tl { three }
      }
      {No~case~found.}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test the code:

\mycommand{21} \% OK - expected output: "one"

\mycommand{26} \% OK - expected output: "No case found."

\mycommand{2a} \% OK - expected output: "No case found."

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the corresponding code with `\str_case_e:nn(TF)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3} % To me, it was not necessary to load in.

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m}
  {
    \keenontex_index:n { #1 }
  }

\cs_new:Nn \keenontex_index:n
  {
   \str_case_e:nnF { \str_item:nn { #1 } { 2 } }
      {
        { 1 } { one   }
        { 2 } { two   }
        { 3 } { three }
      }
      {No~case~found.}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test the code:

\mycommand{21} \% OK - expected output: "one"

\mycommand{26} \% OK - expected output: "No case found."

\mycommand{2a} \% OK - expected output: "No case found."

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @egreg for adding other working solutions to this post! I am sure other, who will read this post in the future, will benefit from both yours and Davids solution.  Yes, I seem to misunderstand the difference between token list and token string variables. Do you have a good example, how to understand the difference between them?